# Angular - mat-paginator not appearing for mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table, paginator

Using Angular 12, I've imported `mat-paginator` with

```js
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

and in `export` I've tried

```js
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
```

and

```js
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {read: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

in the `component.ts`.

In the HTML, I have:

```
<mat-table>
  ...
  <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 4, 6, 8, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
    
</mat-table>
```

The table populates (with a non-formatted header) and the paginator does not appear.
I don't see any error messages. I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mat Table Pagination](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination), `mat-paginator` element is not in `mat-table` element.

### SOLUTION

You need to move out `mat-paginator` element from `mat-table` element.

The HTML template should be looked like below:

```
<div>
  <mat-table>
    ...
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 4, 6, 8, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-78qaar)